# Consequence of withdrawing an approved I130

Tags: usa, greencard

I've got my I130 approved by the London USCIS in 2019, but now mostly because of Covid, my wife and I have decided to settle in the UK. We're considering withdrawing the application, but we're wondering if that's necessary for me to travel to the States to visit friends and family. If this is the only option would there be any consequences for a future I130 application?